# How to create sub-table in tables group by one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, rdbms

I have been doing SQL and I am stuck in one point.
For example, lets say we have a Table Employee with columns Emp_ID(varchar), DELIVERY_TIME(date), Delivery_number(Varchar)

| EMP_ID | DELIVERY_TIME | DELIVERY_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E01 | 21-08-2021 | 4 |
| E01 | 21-08-2019 | 1 |
| E01 | 21-08-2022 | 5 |
| E01 | 21-05-2021 | 2 |
| E01 | 07-08-2021 | 3 |
| E02 | 21-08-2021 | 4 |
| E02 | 21-08-2023 | 5 |
| E02 | 21-08-2020 | 1 |
| E02 | 21-06-2021 | 2 |
| E02 | 06-08-2021 | 3 |

Now I want to manipulate the table by adding one Status column in this by some query, like:

| EMP_ID | DELIVERY_TIME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E01 | 21-08-2021 | IN FUTURE |
| E01 | 21-08-2019 | DELIVERED |
| E01 | 21-08-2022 | IN FUTURE |
| E01 | 21-05-2021 | DELIVERED |
| E01 | 07-08-2021 | DELIVERING |
| E02 | 26-08-2021 | IN FUTURE |
| E02 | 21-08-2023 | IN FUTURE |
| E02 | 21-08-2020 | DELIVERED |
| E02 | 21-06-2021 | DELIVERED |
| E02 | 06-08-2021 | DELIVERING |

Basically, if todays date is 8th September 2021 (08-08-2021) then,

- for dates > , IN - FUTURE
- for date < , delivered
- for max(date) < , delivering.
- from all the dates that are less than current date, the max(latest) of them should be marked as delivering. (Only one will be there). For example, if todays date is 08-08-2021 and in the database we have dates such 07-08-2021, 06-08-2021 and 05-08-2021, then 07-08-2021 should be marked as delivering but rest two should be marked as delivered.

But this is done for every employee ID separately.
Also, if this can be done using only query and no script, that will more preferable. We can also add new EMP_IDs.

Please guide.
Thank you.

Comment: Your rules are unclear, particularly around deliverying.  In addition, the current month is September, so it is not clear if you really mean the current date or some specific date in the past.

Comment: can you explain delivering condition

Comment: Edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I picked maximum from dates where status is not in future
- then compared if we have a delivery_time i.e equal to the maximum date from point above. If yes then it is delivering.

```
with data as (

select 
*,
case when when curdate() < delivery_time then 'In future'
     when  curdate() > delivery_time then 'delivered'
else 'not categorized'
END as status

from [table name]
),

max_date as (
select 
*,
max(case when status not in ('In future') then delivery_time else null end) 
    over(partition by emp_id order by delivery_time desc) as max_delivery_time_when_not_in_future

from data
)

select 
emp_id,
delivery_time,
case 
   when max_delivery_time_when_not_in_future = delivery_time 
   then 'delivering'  else status end as final_status
from max_date
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. This worked, but I am having one issue. If delivery time is null, then also I am getting date in max_delivery_time_when_not_in_future column whereas for in future I am getting date as NULL. Why would this be happening?

Comment: @HardikSomani do you see null in the final_status column? Also can you please upvote and mark the answer as accepted so others can use it

Comment: Hello @trilion, 
Can you please tell some solution for mysql version 5.7?

Comment: Without Window funcitons?

Answer (score 0):

You want a `case` expression with date comparisons.  I think this is the logic:

```
select e.*,
       (case when curdate() <= delivery_time then 'In future'
             when curdate() = delivery_time - interval 1 day then 'Delivering'
             else 'Delivered'
        end) as status
from employee e;
```

If `delivery_time` has a time component, then you want `date(deliery_time)` in the logic.

Notes:

- I would expect a table called `employee` to have one row per employee with the `emp_id` as the primary key.
- I would expect a column called `delivery_time` to have a time component, but your sample data suggests it does not.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Yes, I also made one query like this but the problem with this is it is picking the status for delivering from all the dates but I would like to have it as per the employee code.
Here, with this query only for E02 delivering will come and not for E01.
Also, for your first note, a combination of EMP_ID and delivery number will be primary key.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CASE for this : https://sql.sh/cours/case

```
SELECT *, CASE
 WHEN DELIVERY_TIME < NOW() THEN 'DELIVERED'
 WHEN DELIVERY_TIME > NOW() THEN 'IN_FUTURE'
END
FROM "Users"
```

But I don't know what you mean by

> for max(date) < , delivering.

Comment: Hi. For example, if todays date is 08-08-2021 and in the database we have dates such 07-08-2021, 06-08-2021 and 05-08-2021, then 07-08-2021 should be marked as delivering but rest two should be marked as delivered.